# Can a day, date called be resource?

Tags: dates

I want to prompt an error if another order is already confirmed.

I tried "Another order is confirmed"

Instead may I simply use "Resource isn't available" ?

I'm considering resource same as classroom (resource) isn't available for day, date the user gonna be choose.

Comment: Sounds like you want a message to pop up when someone tries to order/book something that has already been taken? You could just go with the old tried and true "Currently Unavailable".

Comment: Speaking as someone in the software industry, "resource isn't available" is too vague to be helpful.  It could mean that it's already booked or that the room doesn't exist or that the building is closed at that hour. If you know the specific cause of the error, then be specific!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard phrases would be “That day (hour) is already scheduled (taken, booked)” or “That day (hour)  is not available (open)”.

Comment: So what about "Another order is already scheduled"?

Comment: It is not idiomatic to refer to an appointment as an “order.”

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you.

Comment: But can't order be reschedule?

Comment: As I understand it, you are talking about reserving some resource for a specific duration on a particular time and date; you are not buying the resource. It is strange to call that kind of arrangement an "order"; it is usually called a "reservation" or an "appointment." You do not "order a doctor." You schedule an "appointment with a doctor." If the time you want is not available, then what would be said is "The doctor is not available at that time." You would not say "The doctor is unavailable": it implies the doctor is retired, incapacitated, or dead.

Comment: Thank you. Jeff Morrow